# Swift didSet throwing error

Tags: xcode, string, variables, swift, didset

I got the following code:

```
var languageString: String = "" {
        didSet {
            if(languageString != oldValue) {
                configureView()
            }
            if let popoverController = languagePopoverController {
                popoverController.dismissPopoverAnimated(true)
                languagePopoverController = nil

            }
        }
    }
```

The error that is shown is:

> Computed property must have an explicit type

I don't understand the error. I am a beginner. Any help?

EDIT: More code

```
@IBOutlet weak var detailDescriptionLabel: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var webView: UIWebView!

private var languageButton: UIBarButtonItem?
private var languagePopoverController: UIPopoverController?
```

The declaration is simple the rest of the code is on a tableView but that is not giving any errors, is just the string

EDIT 2: More code

```
func configureView() {

    //update the interface for details on the item
    if let detail: AnyObject = self.detailItem {
        if let label = self.detailDescriptionLabel {
            let dict = detail as [String: String]
            //let urlString = dict["url"]!
            let urlString = modifyUrlForLanguage(url: dict["url"]!, language: languageString)
            //detailDescriptionLabel.text = urlString
            label.text = urlString
            let url = NSURL(string: urlString)!
            let request = NSURLRequest(URL: url)
            webView.loadRequest(request)

            let name = dict["name"]!
            title = name
        }
    }

}
```

Here is the configure view. Maybe it helps.

[image: Xcode error view]

Comment: Can you show some surrounding code? What does languagePopoverController look like?

Comment: I copied and pasted your code into an app, and defined `configureView()` as an empty function. Your code compiles perfectly. There is _no such error_. This issue cannot be reproduced. Please make sure that the error is on the line you think it is. There is no "computed property" anywhere in this code. Voting to close as unreproducible.

Comment: Well there is the image, and configureView() if any help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got it, I put an space in the string " " instead of "" I have no idea why but it works.

Comment: @TJ- I have those errors regularly. The space was probably a placeholder character, or an invalid character rendered as space.